# Fluent Api en EF Core No funciona HasDefaultValueSql

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, api-fluent

Tengo esta configuracion en especifico para para tabla "**customer**", el campo **idCatalogTipoDoc** , tiene el valor **por defecto "1"**

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
    
               modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
        {

            entity.ToTable("customer");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Documento)
                .HasName("index_documento");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.RazonSocial)
                .HasName("index_razon");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Condicion)
                .HasColumnName("condicion")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

            entity.Property(e => e.ContactParentId).HasColumnName("contact_parent_id");

            entity.Property(e => e.CreateAt)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.Customer1)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("customer")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

            entity.Property(e => e.Direccion)
                .HasColumnName("direccion")
                .HasMaxLength(1500)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Documento)
                .HasColumnName("documento")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Email)
                .HasColumnName("email")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.IdCatalogTipoDoc)
                .HasColumnName("idCatalogTipoDoc")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("1");

            entity.Property(e => e.IdTipoCustomer).HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");

            entity.Property(e => e.ParentId).HasColumnName("parent_id");

            entity.Property(e => e.RazonSocial)
                .HasColumnName("razonSocial")
                .HasMaxLength(400)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.Supplier).HasColumnName("supplier");

            entity.Property(e => e.Telefono)
                .HasColumnName("telefono")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.TipoDocumento)
                .HasColumnName("tipoDocumento")
                .HasMaxLength(10)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.TotalSale).HasColumnType("decimal(11, 2)");

            entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedAt)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.IdCatalogTipoDocNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Customer)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdCatalogTipoDoc)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_cliente_catalogTipoDocumento");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.IdTipoCustomerNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Customer)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdTipoCustomer)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_customer_tipo_customer");
        });
    
           }
```

Model Customer

```
 public abstract class BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

    }

 public partial class Customer:BaseEntity
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            Cotizacion = new HashSet<Cotizacion>();
            Document = new HashSet<Document>();
            NotaComprobante = new HashSet<NotaComprobante>();
            PaymentsAccounts = new HashSet<PaymentsAccounts>();
            PreVenta = new HashSet<PreVenta>();
        }

        public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Documento { get; set; }
        public string TipoDocumento { get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
        public bool? Condicion { get; set; }
        public int CantSale { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalSale { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue("1")]
        public int IdCatalogTipoDoc { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue("1")]
        public int IdTipoCustomer { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public int ContactParentId { get; set; }
        public bool? Customer1 { get; set; }
        public bool Supplier { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        public CatalogTipoDocumento IdCatalogTipoDocNavigation { get; set; }
        public CatalogTipoCustomer IdTipoCustomerNavigation { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Cotizacion> Cotizacion { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Document> Document { get; set; }
        public ICollection<NotaComprobante> NotaComprobante { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PaymentsAccounts> PaymentsAccounts { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PreVenta> PreVenta { get; set; }
    }
```

Model CatalogTipoDoc

```
public partial class CatalogTipoDocumento:BaseEntity
    {
        public CatalogTipoDocumento()
        {
            Customer = new HashSet<Customer>();
        }

        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public string CodigoSunat { get; set; }
        public bool? Condicion { get; set; }
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

Service

```
Customer customerReturn1 = new Customer()
                {
                RazonSocial = customerDto.name,
                Documento = customerDto.number,
                Email = customerDto.email,
                TipoDocumento = customerDto.identity_document_type_id,
                Direccion = customerDto.address,
                Telefono = customerDto.phone,
                  // Excluyo setear el campo idCatalogTipoDoc

               }
                await _unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.Add(customerReturn1);
                await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();



Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY "FK_cliente_catalogTipoDocumento". El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos "bdComercioMultisucursal", tabla "dbo.catalogTipoDocumento", column 'id'.
Se terminó la instrucción.
```

Me arroja un error de conflictos de claves foréneas , porq **no esta seteando el valor por defecto** de la columna , la operacion es éxito solo cuando lo seteo al crear la entidad.
Debo mencionar que ya agregue el valor por defecto en la bd sqlserver.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En que puedo estar fallando?
Talvez si no he sido lo mas explicito posible o me falta agregar informacion , corriganme , gracias y espero sus recomendaciones sobre mi pregunta

Comment: A tu pregunta, agrega lo que tienes en la clase `Customer`, me late que hace falta especificar mediante alguna data annotation la llave primaria

Comment: @fredyfx, ya agregue lo que me sugeriste, los demas configuraciones de los campos sin funcionan

Comment: Me refería a la clase, al modelo/entidad

Comment: @fredyfx acabo de agregar todo lo posible

Comment: Ahora tengo un mejor panorama de tu escenario, una pregunta más, ¿Cuál es la estructura que tienes en `dbo.catalogTipoDocumento` ? Me refiero a los campos. Por otro lado `[DefaultValue("1")] public int IdCatalogTipoDoc { get; set; }` Aquí ¿Estás seguro que ese default value es el mismo que `((1))` ? Finalmente, ¿Por qué usas `HasDefaultValueSql` ? ¿No sería que quieres darle un valor by default? Si este es el caso, intenta con `HasDefaultValue`

Comment: @fredyfx esa configuración le genere con scaffolding inicialmente , y me genero el valor por defecto asi: ((1)), le cambié a solo: 1 , pero de las dos maneras me genera el error. Y el data annotation [DefaultValue("1")]  también lo agregue , pero al parecer tampoco funciona

Comment: Es posible que sea porque estés poniendo un valor de tipo string, prueba con poner solo el numero 1 como entero, de igual forma no es necesario que uses los atributos sobre la propiedad, mejor solo usa Fluent Api.